# netbeans ServiceProvider not returning variable from method

Tags: java, netbeans, lookup, netbeans-platform, service-provider

I am working on a desktop application with NetBeans Platform. The app will place a map in a topcomponent and the user can draw a layout and other elements on it. The element are stored in hashmap. They are added to the hashmap with mouse gestures.

At this point, I need to retrieve an hashmap object when pressing a button on the UI. The button is in the `moduleA` and the hashmap, maps and objects are defined in `moduleB`. I am trying to do this by using the `ServiceProvider` pattern. So my code is as follows:

```
package org.dhviz.design.gui.buttonToolbar;
//...annotations here...
public final class AssociateConsToPipes implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Collection<? extends DhvizJMapViewerInterface> allHandlers1 = Lookup.
        getDefault().lookupAll(DhvizJMapViewerInterface.class);

        for (DhvizJMapViewerInterface chi1 : allHandlers1) {
            System.out.println(chi1.getMapConsumerHashMap());
        }
    }
}
```

The class implementing the interface is so defined and it is placed in the Module B:

```
@ServiceProvider(service = DhvizJMapViewerInterface.class)
public class DhvizJMapViewer
        extends JMapViewer implements DhvizJMapViewerInterface {

    protected LinkedHashMap<Integer, MapMarkerElementImpl> mapSourceHashMap = null;
    protected LinkedHashMap<Integer, MapMarkerElementImpl> mapConsumerHashMap = null;
    protected LinkedHashMap<Integer, MapPipeImpl> mapPipeHashMap = null;

    public DhvizJMapViewer() {    
        this(new MemoryTileCache(), 8);
        //map controllers for interaction on the map
        mapController = new DefaultDhvizMapController(this);
        this.setScrollWrapEnabled(false);   
    }

    public DhvizJMapViewer(TileCache tileCache, int downloadThreadCount) {
//some init code here
    }
```

I would expect to get the hashmap when pressing the button but i always get an empty object although i can see that the hashmap is not empty.

Can anyone explain me why, please? Thank you very much

Comment: There's a lot of irrelevant code, it's not clear how you initialize the HashMap, try to post minimal (not) working code.